# const keyword after the method name of a class

Tags: c++

I am revisiting C++. I am confused about a syntax. It is not giving me any error but I don't understand how it works.

```
class Car {
private:
    int wheels;
public:
    void setWheels(const int numberOfWheels);
    int getWheels() const;
};

void Car::setWheels(int numberOfWheels) {
    wheels = numberOfWheels;
}
int Car::getWheels() const {
    return wheels;
}
```

What does const do when it is put after the method name? Shouldn't it be put before the return type of the method?

Comment: In C++, member function `int getWheels() const;` is equivalent to (in pseudo-code) `int getWheels(Car const* this);`.  The `const` suffix indicates that the `this` is a const pointer.

Comment: In other words, a `const` method cannot modify any member variables of the object or call any non `const` methods of that object, essentially.